# How to glue a section of $T^*\mathbb{P}^1$ to create an elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Consider a meromorphic section of the cotangent bundle $T^*\mathbb{P}^1$.  Such a section has two poles, say at $0$ and $\infty$ with residues $a,-a$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C}$.  I'd like to take this information and create an elliptic curve, by taking these two poles and gluing in a way prescribed by the residues.  Is anyone aware of such a construction? It may be that there are too many choices being made to get anything interesting.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How do you expect to get an elliptic curve by gluing two points of $\Bbb{P}^1$?

Comment: There is no nonconstant analytic map from $\mathbb P^1$ to any elliptic curve.

Comment: @abx sorry, I agree it's unclear.  The idea I have in mind is to somehow truncate these poles so that the image of the section can be thought of as $\mathbb{P}^1$ with two small discs removed

Comment: The variety obtained from gluing two points on $\mathbb P^1$ can be thought of as the limit of a family of elliptic curves, but is not an elliptic curve itself.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want a nowhere vanishing meromorphic section.

If you want this to (1) nontrivially depend on the section and (2) work in families, this is impossible, as you would get a nonconstant holomorphic map from $\mathbb G_m $ to the moduli stack of elliptic curves, which would lift to a map between the universal covers, i.e. a nonconstant map from $\mathbb C$ to the upper half-plane, which is impossible.